# How to make a CheckBox/EditText object global in Java

Tags: java, android, object, global

So I realize that this question has been asked a lot but I wasn't able to apply any of the others to my situation in a way that I was able to. Basically I am having trouble with global objects in Java as most of my experience is in Python.

Below is my code. Bascially checkbox1 is where I would like it to be, but I don't know how to get my two methods to recognize that it is there. I could fix this by defining checkbox1 in both resetAll as well as doMath but I am sure there is a better way around this

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // right here is where I want my objects so that both resetAll and doMath can use them
    CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


    public void resetAll(View view){
        // do stuff with checkbox1
    }

    public void doMath(View view){
        // do stuff with checkbox1
    }
```

Comment: there is a `onCreate` method, use that method to set the value of the `checkBox1`, also, make `checkBox1` a global variable, the `onCreate` method ensures that its set on activity start and everyone is happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

You cant just `initialized` a `View` before you inflate or set the contentView of the activity or else you'll get a NPE.

**solution:**

Create a global variable which you already did but dont initialized it first.

```
 CheckBox checkbox1;
```

In your `onCreate` method of the `ActionBarActivity` you then initialized it after the `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_for_the_checkbox);`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.internal_main);
    checkbox1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
}
```

After youve done that you can call the `checkbox1` field in both of the methods as long as that method are inside your `MainActivity` class

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I will give it a try and report back. I had tried to put it all in the onCreate but that didn't work (I wasn't expecting it to).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want it to be accessible throughout `MainActivity`, you need to declare that checkbox as a member:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{


    private CheckBox mCheckBoxOne;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activty_your);

        mCheckBoxOne = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    }

    public void resetAll(View view){
        mCheckBoxOne.setChecked(!mCheckBoxOne.isChecked());
    }

    public void doMath(View view){
        mCheckBoxOne.setChecked(!mCheckBoxOne.isChecked());
    }
}
```

if you want it to be accessible from other places, you need to cast the context to `MainActivity` or use `interface` . is that what you want?